# Ethernet Frames on Unidirectional Link

Tags: ethernet

I am working on project to establish system that can only send data (using Ethernet fakeout). Can we send ethernet frames on "Unidirectional link" or physical layer requires two way communication ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to have a uni-directional link - hence the need for protocols such as UDLD (Uni-directional Link Detection) and CFM (Connectivity Fault Management) on Ethernet switches to detect and remedy.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidirectional_Link_Detection
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1ag

You should be able to simulated this quite easily on some switches with fibre optic connections when you disconnect one of the connectors.

I'm not sure that this will be possible on copper links though, as a port won't come up unless auto-negotiation has succeeded, which requires bi-directional communication:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation

Comment: Can we some how manually set the parameters that are negotiated during the process or disable auto-negotiation. Instead of using optical card I am trying this [link] (https://ephemer1c.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/data-diode/)

Comment: I don't think disabling auto-negotiation would change the need for the port to see voltage on appropriate pairs in order to detect link.  As for the Data-Diode - that seems like an overly complicated, completely non-scalable method of doing something a stateless ACL/filter could achieve quite easily.  Block TCP, Allow UDP in one direction, block all in the return direction.  No crappy media convertors required..

Comment: Yes, that's one way of doing it. But as in [link] optics makes sure nothing comes in even if other side is compromised.